# I want to take backup of site folder from admin side,not using cron

Tags: php

I want to take backup of site folder but not using cron. 
I have used copy command,but it is taking too much time,is there any other way or script i can copy site folder?

Answer (score 1):

I had a problem with a similar limitation on a cronjob.

My solution was to create a Shell Script **cronback.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh

#############################
#       USER SETTINGS       #
#############################


 # MySQL Database Server
  SQLHOST="__DBHOSTNAME__"
 # MySQL Username
  SQLUSER="__DBUSERNAME__"
 # MySQL Password
  SQLPASS="__PASSWORD__"

 # Backup Target Directory - Ensure it is outside of the HTTP Root Directory
  BACKUPDIR="__BACKUP_TO__"
 # HTTP Root Directory
  HTTPDOCDIR="__BACKUP_FROM__"

 # Retain Backups for X Days
  RETAINDAYS=28


#############################
#   Do Not Edit Below This  #
#############################

 # Execution Timestamp
  ETIME=$(date +"%Y%m%d_%H%M%S")

#############################

echo "Automated Server Backup Script"
echo "      ----==========----"
echo ""

echo "Web Root Backup"
echo "===="
 # Get a List of Site Folder
  cd $HTTPDOCDIR
  SITELIST=`find -type d -maxdepth 1 | sort`
 # Loop through Folders
  for SITEONE in $SITELIST; do
    FOLDER=${SITEONE//.\/}
   # Do Not try and Backup the Whole Directory in One Hit
    if [ $FOLDER != '.' ]; then
      echo "| - $FOLDER"
      FIXED=${FOLDER//./_}
      SOURCE=$FOLDER
      TARGET=$BACKUPDIR$FIXED"_"$ETIME".gz"
      `tar -czf $TARGET $SOURCE &`
      echo "|   \ - Compressed to "$FIXED"_"$ETIME".gz"
    fi
  done
 # End Loop
echo ""

echo "MySQL Database Backup"
echo "===="
 # Get a List of Databases
  dblist=`mysql --host="$SQLHOST" --user="$SQLUSER" --password="$SQLPASS" --execute="show databases;"`
 # Loop through List of Databases
  for dbitem in $dblist; do
   # Do Not try and Backup the Header of 'Database' - Der!
    if [ $dbitem != 'Database' ]; then
     # Perfom the Backup
      DBFILE=$dbitem"_"$ETIME".sql.gz"
      echo "| - $dbitem"
      `mysqldump --host="$SQLHOST" --user="$SQLUSER" --password="$SQLPASS" --add-drop-table $dbitem | gzip > "$BACKUPDIR$DBFILE" &`
      echo "|   \ - Saved to '$DBFILE'"
    fi
  done
 # End Loop
echo ""

echo "Removing Old Backups"
echo "===="
echo "(Removing Backups older than $RETAINDAYS days.)"
 # Get a List of Files to Delete
  TODELETE=`find $BACKUPDIR -name '*.gz' -type f -mtime +$RETAINDAYS`
 # Loop through Files
  for ONEFILE in $TODELETE; do
    echo "| - $ONEFILE"
    `rm -f $ONEFILE`
    echo "|   \ - deleted"
  done
 # End Loop
echo ""

echo ""
echo "Backup Script Complete."
echo ""
```

I then have a PHP script which calls that Script

```
<?php

set_time_limit( 2400 );

ob_start();
passthru( '__cronback.sh__' );
$retVal = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();

@mail( 'me@myemail.com' , 'Cron Backup' , $retVal );
```

I then trigger this function every week (so the 28 day period gives me 4 snapshots) and I get an email telling me what was backed up and what was deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean is there any other command for copying than copy? No.

Answer (score 0):

I use zip-ing. I just zip everything up, and save it.

Check this: [UPHP folder backup](http://uphp.wordpress.com/2011/01/31/uphp-folder-backup/)

But if what you have is taking too long, there really is no faster way than to copy it.